# TypeError: Cannot read property 'elementRef' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I tried to run unit test case but it throws error message **TypeError: Cannot read property 'elementRef' of undefined**

list.component.ts

```
const elementHeader= this.listTable['elementRef'].nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.adf-datatable-header  > .adf-datatable-row')[0];
      elementHeader.classList.add("testCheck");
      let rowsList = this.listTable.rows;
      if(rowsList){
      for(let i=0;i<=rowsList.length;i++){
          if(i==0){
              const elementBody= this.listTable['elementRef'].nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.adf-datatable-body  > .adf-datatable-row')[0];
              elementBody.classList.add("testCheck");
          }
           
          const elementBody= this.listTable['elementRef'].nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.adf-datatable-body  > .adf-datatable-row')[i];
           if( rowsList[i].dtPurged && rowsList[i].dtPurged != null ){
               elementBody.classList.add("testCheck");
           }
       
        }
```

list.component.spec.ts

```
import { ElementRef, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
let h1: HTMLElement;
  let elRef: ElementRef;
 beforeEach(() => {
 h1 = component.listTable['elementRef'].nativeElement.querySelector('.adf-datatable-body  > .adf-datatable-row');
 });
```

Please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Define listTable before the h1:

```
beforeEach(() => {
component.listTable = // Define here
 h1 = component.listTable['elementRef'].nativeElement.querySelector('.adf-datatable-body  > .adf-datatable-row');
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply
For declaration of value to the component.listTable what need to be given. Please let me know

Comment: In the list.component.ts, copy the value of ```this.listTable ```and use it in the spec file, at ```component.listTable = /*that value*/```. This should do the work. If still facing the issue.. please add the whole component code in the question or replicate it on stackblitz, so it's easier to check 